itextSharp Error: Error en espacio de tabla en HTML
Actualmente estoy generando mi diseño con HTML utilizando la propiedad ParseXHtml del itextsharp, sin embargo al agregar el border = 1 a la tabla se puede observar las lineas que estan entre celdas se ven mas gruesas debido que hay un espacio entre celdas ya he intentado agregando el estilo y no lo reconoce
table.border-table td, table.border-table th  {     
        border: 1px solid black;   
    }
    table.border-table {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: collapse;  
    }



Me parece que la generación de ese espacio es "normal", si no lo deseas, define border-spacing: 0; :
table.border-table {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing:0;  
    }

